# Java 8 optional: ifPresent return object orElseThrow exception

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I'm trying to make something like this:

```
 private String getStringIfObjectIsPresent(Optional<Object> object){
        object.ifPresent(() ->{
            String result = "result";
            //some logic with result and return it
            return result;
        }).orElseThrow(MyCustomException::new);
    }
```

This won't work, because ifPresent takes Consumer functional interface as parameter, which has void accept(T t). It cannot return any value. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper usage of Optional.ifPresent()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228279/proper-usage-of-optional-ifpresent)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Actually what you are searching is: [Optional.map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-). Your code would then look like:

```
object.map(o -> "result" /* or your function */)
      .orElseThrow(MyCustomException::new);
```

I would rather omit passing the `Optional` if you can. In the end you gain nothing using an `Optional` here. A slightly other variant:

```
public String getString(Object yourObject) {
  if (Objects.isNull(yourObject)) { // or use requireNonNull instead if NullPointerException suffices
     throw new MyCustomException();
  }
  String result = ...
  // your string mapping function
  return result;
}
```

If you already have the `Optional`-object due to another call, I would still recommend you to use the `map`-method, instead of `isPresent`, etc. for the single reason, that I find it more readable (clearly a subjective decision ;-)).

Answer (score 33):

Two options here:

Replace `ifPresent` with `map` and use `Function` instead of `Consumer`

```
private String getStringIfObjectIsPresent(Optional<Object> object) {
    return object
            .map(obj -> {
                String result = "result";
                //some logic with result and return it
                return result;
            })
            .orElseThrow(MyCustomException::new);
}
```

Use `isPresent`:

```
private String getStringIfObjectIsPresent(Optional<Object> object) {
    if (object.isPresent()) {
        String result = "result";
        //some logic with result and return it
        return result;
    } else {
        throw new MyCustomException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the second option is not the recommended way to use Optionals

Comment: `map` is not intended nor designed for this usage. It always has a return type, so it's better to do `return someOptional.orElseThrow(() -> ...);` -- it is unclear if OP intended to return something or not.

Comment: This is better answer to map version.

Comment: @josh could you explain why do you think `map` shouldn't be used, and instead we must return an `Optional` value. Because returning `Optional` effectively means that you need to add few more lines later to see if the intended item is present or not.

Comment: You don't return `Optional<T>`. If you do `someOptional.orElseThrow(() -> ...)` then the underlying value is returned _if there is one_, else the exception you specified in the lambda is thrown. This is better than using `.map` because that function is meant to transform one thing into another, it is not necessary unless you're massaging the optional value in some way.

Answer (score 18):

Use the `map`-function instead. It transforms the value inside the optional.

Like this:

```
private String getStringIfObjectIsPresent(Optional<Object> object) {
    return object.map(() -> {
        String result = "result";
        //some logic with result and return it
        return result;
    }).orElseThrow(MyCustomException::new);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I'd prefer mapping after making sure the value is available

```
private String getStringIfObjectIsPresent(Optional<Object> object) {
   Object ob = object.orElseThrow(MyCustomException::new);
    // do your mapping with ob
   String result = your-map-function(ob);
  return result;
}
```

or one liner

```
private String getStringIfObjectIsPresent(Optional<Object> object) {
   return your-map-function(object.orElseThrow(MyCustomException::new));
}
```

Comment: first solution is the cleanest and most readable of all solutions in this entire thread

Answer (score 1):

The example u put is not a good example. Optional shouldn't be sent as parameter into another function. Good practice is always sending non-null parameter into function. So that we know always that the input will not be null. This can decrease our code uncertainty.