# Should I prefer the `ifPresent` method to the `isPresent` one?

Tags: java, option-type

I have this code using the latter:

```
Optional<String> subject = Optional.ofNullable(claims.get().getSubject());
if (subject.isPresent()) {
  UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(subject.get());
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
      null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
  authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
  logger.debug("Security - The request authenticated fine from the JWT Access token");
  return authentication;
} else {
  throw new BadCredentialsException("The authentication token " + optToken + " did not contain a subject.");
}
```

I'm trying to refactor this using the `ifPresent` method.

Should I have the `userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername` service call before the functional method call ? If so, how to ? How to return an object of type different than the functional method type ?

I'm on Java 12.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485751/java-8-optional-ifpresent-return-object-orelsethrow-exception I think your question is already answered here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `map` method to transform the value of the `Optional`.
After transforming it, you can use the `orElseThrow` method to unpack the `Optional`, throwing an exception if it was empty.

Something like this:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(claims.get().getSubject())
               .map(userDetailsService::loadUserByUsername)
               .map(userDetails -> {
                   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = 
                       new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                           userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                   authentication.setDetails(
                       new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                   return authentication;
               })
               .orElseThrow(() -> new BadCredentialsException(
                  "The authentication token " + optToken + " did not contain a subject."));
```

However, in your specific case, it might be simpler to not use `Optional` at all. You could just check for null immediately.

```
String subject = claims.get().getSubject();
if (subject == null) {
    throw new BadCredentialsException(
        "The authentication token " + optToken + " did not contain a subject.");
}

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = ... ;
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could use `orElseThrow`, which throws an exception if the value is not present:

```
String subjectValue = subject.orElseThrow(() ->
    new BadCredentialsException("The authentication token " + optToken + " did not contain a subject."));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `ifPresent` you could do something like

```
subject.ifPresent(s -> {
     UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(s);
     ...
});
```

but since you are throwing on a missing subject why not simply do

```
String subject = Optional.ofNullable(claims.get().getSubject())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new BadCredentialsException(...));
UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(subject);
...
```