# Using consumer and throw exception in Optional

Tags: java

Is it possible to rewrite the following using Optional ? It seems to me when the situation requires to throw exception then using Optional may not be a good idea ?

```
Item item = service.get(id);

if (item == null) {
 throw new ItemNotFoundException();
}

item.setValue(false);
itemDao.update(item);
```

Attempt 1:

```
Optional.ofNullable(service.get(id))
  .ifPresent(item -> {
    item.setValue(false);
    itemDao.update(item);
  });   // cannot throw exception inside the consumer
```

Attempt 2:

```
Optional.ofNullable(service.get(id))
  .map(item -> {
    item.setValue(false);
    itemDao.update(item);
  })   
  .orElseThrow(new ItemNotFoundException()); //can throw exception here but the usage of map is not correct
```

Comment: In the first place, `Optional` is supposed to be used as return type by the method. If possible, change `service.get` to return `Optional`.

Comment: Don't try to turn every null check into something that uses `Optional`. If statements that check for null are not deprecated.

Comment: You have to write `orElseThrow(ItemNotFoundException::new)`. I.e. you create a supplier that can create the exception **on demand**.

Comment: Ideally you let the method return `Optional` in the first place. If thats not feasible, I would stick with regular if-else. Unless you want to return an Optional yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 optional: ifPresent return object orElseThrow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485751/java-8-optional-ifpresent-return-object-orelsethrow-exception)

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: Besides the answers, I agree with @Sweeper. A simple if-null check is a clear control flow and suits perfectly fine for this case.

Comment: @Sweeper It may not directly, but it's exactly the same question with some discussions going on.

Comment: Note that you can always call `ifPresent` and `orElseThrow` as separate statements. You don't have to always chain these methods.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in answers before - the service method should return an optional.
If you absolutely want to use an `Optional` with the unchanged service method then do it as follows:

```
Item item = Optional.ofNullable(service.get(id)).orElseThrow(ItemNotFoundException::new);

item.setValue(false);
itemDao.update(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the item on map.

```
Optional.ofNullable(service.get(id))
.map(item -> {
   item.setValue(false);
   itemDao.update(item);
   return item;
}).orElseThrow(ItemNotFoundException::new);
```