# Using optional to populate value in a Map

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and still learning Optionals. I understood its used to avoid Null Pointer Exception.

I have a piece of code wherein I want to use optional, which is like this:

```
    final MetadataExtractor<FCAddress> metadataExtractor = t -> {
        final Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
        metadata.put("senderCountryCode", t.getCountryCode());
        metadata.put("senderState", t.getState());
        metadata.put("senderPostalCode",t.getPostalCode());
        return metadata;
    };
```

Here, my use case is, if the SenderState is empty, i.e. t.getState() is empty, I want the map field to to be empty, that is not populated.

I tried something like this:

```
    final MetadataExtractor<FCAddress> metadataExtractor = t -> {
        final Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
        metadata.put("senderCountryCode", t.getCountryCode());
        Optional<String> senderState = Optional.of(t.getState());
        senderState.ifPresent(metadata.put("senderState", t.getState());
        metadata.put("senderPostalCode",t.getPostalCode());
        return metadata;
    };
```

But this gives a compilation error, where am I going wrong in this?
Error is: "ifPresent
(java.util.function.Consumer)
in Optional cannot be applied"

Comment: Why would you use `Optional` here? Just use a plain old if.

Comment: If you get an error (compile or runtime) then include it in your question.

Comment: `ifPresent` takes a `Consumer`. You're giving it a String.

Comment: @AxelH OP is using **if**Present, not **is**. And no, OP doesn't want `map`.

Comment: @AndyTurner yep ... my bad

Comment: When you say "t.getState() is empty" do you mean *empty*, or do you mean *null*? They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular code the use of `Optional` is not useful because you don't like to add an `Optional` to the map, but only skip `null` values.

The simplest solution that doesn't create new objects is adding a check on value of `t.getState()` as follow:

```
final MetadataExtractor<FCAddress> metadataExtractor = t -> {
    final Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
    metadata.put("senderCountryCode", t.getCountryCode());
    if (t.getState() != null) {
       metadata.put("senderState", t.getState());
    }
    metadata.put("senderPostalCode",t.getPostalCode());
    return metadata;
};
```

Just for studying purpose the solution of *GhostCat* works with an `Optional`:

> `senderState.ifPresent(() -> metadata.put("senderState", t.getState());`

the complete example will be:

```
final MetadataExtractor<FCAddress> metadataExtractor = t -> {
    final Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
    metadata.put("senderCountryCode", t.getCountryCode());

    // Here you create a not useful object that can be replaced with a simple if
    Optional<String> senderState = Optional.ofNullable(t.getState());

    // Here you create a second not necessary object because a lambda
    // espression is an instance of an anonimous class implementing
    // the corresponding interface
    senderState.ifPresent(() -> 
         metadata.put("senderState", t.getState()
    );
    metadata.put("senderPostalCode",t.getPostalCode());
    return metadata;
};
```

Note that this solution will create two unnecessary objects:

- The explicit `Optional` `senderState`
- and another object for the `Consumer` created as lambda expression inside the `ifPresent` method

Comment: of() will throw an exception if t.getState() is null. To make it work, ofNullable() must be used.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a Consumer (a lambda) to ifPresent:

```java
senderState.ifPresent(state -> metadata.put("state", state);
// important: the Consumer always receive a parameter.
// An empty value `() ->` is not valid!
```

The lambda will only get executed in case senderState **is present** (that means, is not null).

BTW it's very important to construct your `senderState` by using `Optional.ofNullable(...)`! Otherwise, it'll throw an NPE.

Check out an in-depth tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional

Comment: @AndyTurner once you're in the lambda you don't need to use `t.getState()`, but `state`.

Answer (score 2):

> still learning Optionals. I understood its used to avoid Null Pointer Exception.

Not necessarily. They are rather a *mean* that allows you to have *something* that represents "nothing".

Regarding your actual compile error:

```
senderState.ifPresent(metadata.put("senderState", t.getState());
```

`ifPresent()` wants a **consumer**. From the javadoc:

```
public void ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer)
```

> If a value is present, invoke the specified consumer with the value, otherwise do nothing.

metadata.put() isn't a consumer. That is an ordinary method call on that map! And it will return a the "value" type of your map, so a String. Strings aren't Consumers!

Long story short: if you really want to use `ifPresent()` here, then you would probably want to pass a lambda expression (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228279/proper-usage-of-optional-ifpresent) for some examples).

In your case,

```
senderState.ifPresent(state -> metadata.put("senderState", state));
```

should do.

Answer (score 2):

Just to present a totally different approach to the problem:

Put everything into the map, and then remove the null values after:

```
metadata.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

This is a lot neater syntactically, but may or may not be faster because of doing something and then undoing it, as opposed to just not doing it in the first place.