# What function of the Java Boolean class makes it act as a boolean in an if statement or expression

Tags: java, class, boolean

I presume if I write:

```
Boolean doIt; 
...
if (doIt) { doSomething();}
```

There is some function in the Boolean class that gets called that returns a boolean that the if statement evaluates to decide to `doSomething()` or not.  What is the name of that function so I can write a class like:

```
public class MagicBoolean {

    public boolean toBoolean() { // this is the function name I am looking for
       return true;
    }
...
MagicBoolean doIt;
...
if (doIt) { doSomething(); } // doIt.toBoolean() is implicitly called here
```

and get the same effect.  And, no I don't want to extend Boolean as the logic in toBoolean will be much more complex than checking a simple value and it may involve computation or it may be a memo-ized value, but I don't want the uses of that "value" to know or care.  It's just a flag to tell them that the strategy being used wants them to do this (or that) at this particular time.

Comment: This is called [auto(un)boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8). And your own classes cannot do it. Not without custom code generation/replacement.

Comment: So, there is no equivalent of operator boolean() like in C++.

Comment: There is no operator overloading in Java.

Comment: So I presume I need to write something like:
```
if (a.get()) { doSomething(); }
```

Comment: I think you need to think a bit more OO and a bit less procedurally. For example `a.ifSomething(this::doSomething)`.

Comment: Basically closely to how [Optional.ifPresent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228279/proper-usage-of-optional-ifpresent) works.

Comment: Note that Groovy _does_ have this capability; the name of the "magic method" is `asBoolean()`.