# Do I need to check the null for optional object itself before use ? - optionalObj == null

Tags: java, java-8

When we use the Java 8 Optional feature, do we need to check the optional object itself is null before we call `isPresent()` ?  see the 2nd line in my code below.

```
Optional<entity> optionalEntity = myRepository.findById(dao.getId());
if (optionalEntity != null) {  // is this check need?
    if(optionalEntity.isPresent() {
        MyEntity entityToUpdate = optionalEntity.get();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Any API that returns a null `Optional` object is working hard to miss the point. And if you need to be that defensive in your code, then life is really hard. "No" *should* be the answer.

Comment: You never *need* to check anything for null if you are sure nobody ever uses null. If all devs follow some basic common sense practices (lets hope so) then no, you do not need to check the `optionalEntity` for null. If it ever crashes because `optionalEntity` is `null` track down whoever return `null` for an `Optional` and give them a good slap.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to.

In theory, `Optional<>`s can be null but shouldn't be as the empty value would make more sense.

Returning a `null` `Optional<>` value is just bad API design.

[Spring JPA uses `Optional` instead of `null`, just like it should do](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability) so you can skip the additional null check.

Also, using `Optional#ifPresent` indicates that you are using `Optional` incorrectly. You may want to use [the other methods of `Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) instead.

If you need to execute something if the Optional has a value, you can use the method `Optional#ifPresent`:

```
someOptional.ifPresent(value->doSomething(value));
```

This might not seem like a big advantage but it works well with other methods like Optional#map:

```
someOptional.map(value->value.getSomething()).ifPresent(value->doSomething(value))
```

`Optional#map` transforms the object in the `Optional` using the passed lambda expression.

`Optional#filter` replaces tte object in the `Optional` with `null` (empty `Optional`) if the object doesn't match the passed condition.

Comment: why what is the problem of `isPresent() `? why suggest other methods?

Comment: `isPresent()` is basically the same as a regular null-check on a nullable object. The purpose of `Optional<>` is to get away from this.

Comment: can you pls update the answer then with which method to use? or the better approach? because some articles mentioned to use isPresent()

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to check the null for optional object itself before use?

No, either do not use an `Optional<T>`, or if you're using it, try not to get in a habit of checking optional instances against `null`, as this defeats the purpose of `Optional<T>`.

Remember, that:

1. `Optional<T>` was not designed with an intention to swap `null` checks. It's a wrapper/container for a possibly existing object, nothing more, nothing less; therefore, in a lot of cases, it is just a nice, beautified and a concise alternative of boilerplate null-checks, with an addition, that you can chain activities, in just a line, when object is present;
2. `Optional<T>` is not serializable.

Cay Horstmann nicely says, that:

> The key to using Optional effectively is to use a method that either produces an alternative if the value is not present, or consumes the value only if it is present.

You can use [`ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) and if a value is present, you can chain some corresponding activity calls.

[`isPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--) can also be used, in some cases, and it returns boolean; you can then [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) an instance, if it `isPresent()`.

Additionally, you can find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228279/proper-usage-of-optional-ifpresent) useful.